# topic heading goes behind header while clicking on scroll to topic link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

currently working on reacts Gatsby documentation site with has lots of cross-linking internal and pages but the problem correctly facing is scrolling to the topic .. when I click on any which content that has a topic id (see below link example) so when I click on below link it should navigate to other page and scroll to that particular element which has #start-recording-a-session id but the problem is the element goes behind header because I have fixed Header div. I have solved the problem using **scrollMarginBlockStart** but it works on the same page only when it comes to other pages(internal mdx page) when I click on a particular link it navigates me to other pages and then scrolls to that specific topic but this **scrollMarginBlockStart** logic does not work but classes apply on that element but it does not work.

/docs/references/sdks/pixel/ios/abc/xyc/#start-recording-a-session

```
      const innerFunction = useCallback(() => {
    const anchorTags = document.querySelectorAll('#main a')

    anchorTags.forEach((anchorTag) => {
      const href = anchorTag.getAttribute('href')
      const ariaLabel = anchorTag.getAttribute('aria-label')

      if (href && href.startsWith('#') && ariaLabel) {
        anchorTag.parentElement.style.scrollMarginBlockStart = '70px'
        anchorTag.parentElement.style.msScrollMarginBlockStart = '70px' // IE/Edge
        anchorTag.parentElement.style.MozScrollMarginBlockStart = '70px' // Firefox
        anchorTag.parentElement.style.WebkitScrollMarginBlockStart = '70px' // Chrome/Safari
      }
    })
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    innerFunction()
  }, [innerFunction])
```